# Linq get unique clients

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I try to get a unique list of children of the children via linq. I mean, I have `client`s of `bar`s living in `cities`. Bars can have same clients.

I need to have a unique list of clients, so I do like this (code fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nuKGcn)):

```
public class Program
{
    class Client { public int Id { get; set; } }
    
    class Bar 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Client> Clients;
    }
    
    class City
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Bar> Bars;
    }
    
    public static void Main() 
    {
        var clients = new Client[] 
        { 
            new Client() { Id = 5 }, 
            new Client() { Id = 9 } 
        };
        
        Bar b1 = new Bar() { Id = 1, Clients = clients };
        Bar b2 = new Bar() { Id = 2, Clients = clients };

        City c1 = new City() { Id = 1, Bars = new Bar[] { b1, b2 } };
        City c2 = new City() { Id = 2, Bars = new Bar[] { } };
        
        List<City> cities = new List<City>() { c1, c2 };
        
        var barClients = cities.Select(c => c.Bars.Select(b => b.Clients));
        
        foreach (var c in barClients)
            Console.WriteLine(c.Id);            
    }
}
```

However this does not work (it says about the collection of collections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want something like this?

```
var barClients = cities.SelectMany(s => s.Bars.SelectMany(x => x.Clients)).Distinct();
```

More about [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0)

Distinct will "remove" duplicated clients

Comment: so, I did just with select, and it seems it not take a collection as return type...

Comment: Good answer! @Serge, maybe you also want to implement IEquatable<> for getting dinstict on Id if there are duplicate Client-objects. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0

Comment: @TorbjörnHansson good remark, so I did `public bool Equals(BaseEntity other) { return this.Id.Equals(other.Id) && this.Id != 0; }`

Comment: True, but in simple scenario default equality comparer it's enough unless you assume add more properties to Client class

Comment: @janek9971 does the default scenario use `Id` for comparison?

Comment: @Serge basically yes, but first it compares by reference, since you have duplicates same instances it will not compare value of properties but only this instances.

Something like this:

    `if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;  return Id == other.Id;`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use GroupBy and Select if you don't want to use Distinct

```
var barClients = cities.SelectMany(s => s.Bars.SelectMany(x => x.Clients))
                       .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                       .Select(x => x.First());
```